# Audio Playlist in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I Just solved it, thanks to everyone.**

I'm trying to understand how to do Audio Playlists in html so I tried to follow the tutorial in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtZCMTtP-0Y (code presented below), to achieve my goal. The only problem is that it doesn't work, when a song ends it returns always to the second song on the list, also the console tells me there's a "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException", that I don't know how to solve.

```
function audioPlayer() {
    var currentSong = 0;
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("playlist li a")[0];
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
    $("#playlist li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
        currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
    });

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function() {
        currentSong++;
        if (currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length) {
            currentSong = 0;
        }
        $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
        $("#playlist li:eq(" + currentSong + ")").addClass("current-song");
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
    });
}
```

Also, with css I tried to make the name of the song that is playing blue, but what happens is that all the name of the songs i click get blue, instead of just the one playing.

```
#audioPlayer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#playlist li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#playlist .current-song a {
  color: #0b80f7;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

**I Just solved it, thanks to everyone.**

Comment: try to add this in javascript  function audioPlayer(){  var currentSong = 0; and in html audio tag try to add this  preload="none"

Comment: @godfather My file didn't save or I didn't write it here, but i already had added var currentSong = 0 :P sorry, I'll edit it. I tried what you said though and it did'nt solve the problem :c

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error where you wrote `lenght` instead of `length` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @KevinPastor Ups, you're right, editing it. But it also didn't solve the problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what was wrong was that I was using the "a" element inside a span like this:

```
<li class="current-song"> <span><a href="../music/lights.mp3"> Lights Down Low</a></span><span>3:43</span></li>
```

When instead what I should be doing is:

```
<li class="current-song"> <a href="../music/lights.mp3"> Lights Down Low</a><span>3:43</span></li>
```

So that based on my script it can work... Sometimes I'm really stupid. Thanks to all the people that commented!